# How to disable share this hover effect?

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I need to disable the mouseover popup ShareThis uses. According to the documentation I just need to add "onhover: false” to the options. However this does not work. This does not even work in their [documentation](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/hover-effects) on how to disable the hover effect.

How can I stop this hover event from executing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it possible to unbind the hover event or something?

Comment: Link is no longer working...

Answer (score 8):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   stLight.options({
      publisher:'b8a24e9b-84db-4fe8-8950-ea6f0e28e2fa',
      onhover: false
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, place the onhover:false in the widget section under the stLight.options